# Integral lnxˆ2 why not u-sub first?

Tags: calculus, integration

This is my first time posting so I apologize if there are errors in what I am trying to ask.

I am working on $\int \ln^2(x) \mathrm{d}x$, worked it through and then attempted to use integration by parts. I thought I was on the right track but ended up completely off and saw on the answer key that only parts were used. I can't seem to find the reasoning behind why I cannot use u-sub first. Any input would be helpful. :)

Thanks!

Comment: We are more likely to understand the details of your question if you show us your work.  The [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) might help.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter if you do the substitution or not. If you do parts straight away, you need to do i.b.p. twice to get the answer. If you do the $u$-sub, then parts, then you also need to do i.b.p. twice. So the $u$-sub method is slightly longer, but not wrong.

If you do the substitution $u=\ln(x)$, then $dx=e^u\,du$, so the integral becomes $$\int u^2 e^u\,du$$ This can be integrated by parts to give $$e^u(u^2-2u+2)=x((\ln(x))^2-2\ln(x)+2)$$ which is the same answer as you'd get if you did parts on the initial integral.

Comment: Good to know I wasn't totally wrong. My work was vastly different than the answer key so I got a tad worried. I need to practice more so I can identify when to do what process. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @johndoe for letting me know that u-sub isn't totally wrong...its just the longer route. Practice makes perfect, and in this case, it'll help me identify when to use what to be more proficient. I really appreciate the quick responses too!

Comment: You don't need IBP at all if you use a sensible Ansatz, $(au^2+bu+c)e^u+C$.

Comment: @JenA No problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem in the following manner. Set $\ln x = u$ then $\mathrm{d}x = e^u \mathrm{d}u$ and the integral becomes:
$$ \int u^2e^u\mathrm{d}u $$
which can be easily solved using integration by parts.